# Declaring PROCEDURE with dynamic variable based on user input

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures, azure-data-studio

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = N'dbo'
    AND SPECIFIC_NAME = N'Reports'
    AND ROUTINE_TYPE = N'PROCEDURE')
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.Reports        
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Reports (@Date_of_Purchase DATE)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT o.O_Id, o.Sale_Price, o.Private_Band, c.Type, c.Points_Issued, o.Date_of_Purchase
    FROM Order_Details o
    LEFT JOIN Transaction_Historys c ON o.Date_of_Purchase = c.Date_of_Purchase
    WHERE o.Date_of_Purchase > @Date_of_purchase
END
GO

EXECUTE dbo.Reports
GO
```

I want to make `o.Date_of_Purchase > DATEADD(d,@date,getdate())`. `@date` should be dynamic values based on user input, how to declare the days(`@date`) dynamically.

I get an error when executing the stored procedure:

> Must declare the scalar variable

Comment: Can u pls tell me help me now.@date should get dynamic valus from user and return the select statement records

Comment: Your procedure has a parameter, so what's the problem here? Apart from that you call the procedure inside itself, without said parameter (or *is* that the problem?)

Comment: I get an error must-declare-the-scalar-variable-error-for-stored-procedure

Comment: I shuld get the records whose dateofppurchase value is lessthan dynamic value like less than 90days,120dyas like that

Comment: This `o.Date_of_Purchase > DATEADD(d,@date,getdate())` gives records 90 days in the future more beyond. Is that what you want? Or do you want the last 90 days?

Comment: Perhaps Erland's discussion of [dynamic search conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) will give you some inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to create and run a procedure which takes a parameter for days, adds those days to today's date and then carries out a query filtering against that date.

The main point is you need to create, initialise, and pass in the parameters.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Reports
(
    @Days INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT o.O_Id, o.Sale_Price, o.Private_Band, c.Type, c.Points_Issued, o.Date_of_Purchase
    FROM Order_Details o
    LEFT JOIN Transaction_Historys c ON o.Date_of_Purchase = c.Date_of_Purchase
    WHERE o.Date_of_Purchase > DATEADD(DAY, @Days, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

    RETURN 0;
END
GO

-- Create and initialise parameter.
DECLARE @Days INT = 90;

-- Execute SP, passing in our parameter
EXECUTE dbo.Reports @Days;
```